# how do you get the name of a package that dispatched an intent in android?

Tags: android, android-intent, package, broadcastreceiver

I have a service setup to receive a PACKAGE_ADDED and a PACKAGE_REMOVED intent from all `<data android:scheme="package" />`

I receive the intent correctly, but I need to know how to use the Intent and Context classes from onReceive to get the name and label of the application that was added or removed.

I have been able to use Intent.getDataString() to get the uri string of the package, but don't really know where to go from there.

Thanks.

Comment: As far as I know this isn't possible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what the `Uri` looks like. I would assume it contains the package name (e.g., `com.commonsware.my.really.awesome.app`). If so, you can use `PackageManager` to get the rest of the details regarding that application.

Comment: Yeah, I need to use PackageManager. I can't use it in the BroadcastReceiver but rather need to figure out how to send it to a Service the receiver is starting.